# Enable/Disable Validators in Gridview when adding row dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have issue to disable/enable validators for newly add row to gridview which is in Update panel, If I remove Update panel then it's worked perfect, and If I add Update panel then it stops working. I have created sample page.

Default.aspx.

```
<head>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript">        $(document).ready(function () {            $('table > tbody > tr .wrapper [class*="onoff"] option:selected').each(function (index) {                adjustValidators(this);            });            $('[class*="onoff"] select').change(function () {                adjustValidators($('option:selected', this)[0]);            });        });                    </script></head>


<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="18000">    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager><asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">    <asp:View ID="group_Group1" runat="server">        <div class="group group1">            <asp:Button ID="btnNext0_top" runat="server" Text="Next >>" OnClick="btnNext_Click" ValidationGroup="surveyValidate0" />                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPNew" UpdateMode="Conditional">                    <ContentTemplate>                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="repeatregion_RRSectionSS" RegionName="RRSectionSS" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="-1" CssClass="rrsectionss">                            <Columns>                                <asp:TemplateField>                                    <ItemTemplate>                                        <div id="wrapper_ONOFF" runat="server" class="wrapper onoff">                                            <div class='statement  onoff' id="statement_ONOFF" runat="server">                                                Required Validator :</div>                                            <div class='question  onoff' id="questionlayer_ONOFF" runat="server">                                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="question_ONOFF" ValidationGroup="surveyValidate0" Data='<%# Eval("ONOFF") %>' Val='<%# Eval("ONOFF_selectedValue") %>'>                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Off" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="On"></asp:ListItem>                                                </asp:DropDownList>                                            </div>                                        </div>                                        <div id="wrapper_testsssss" runat="server" class="wrapper testsssss">                                            <div class='statement  testsssss' id="statement_testsssss" runat="server">                                                Sample Text                                            </div>                                            <div class='question  testsssss' id="questionlayer_testsssss" runat="server">                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="question_testsssss" type="shortans" Columns='40' ValidationGroup="surveyValidate0" Text='<%# Common.DecodeXML(Eval("testsssss")) %>'></asp:TextBox>                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_question_testsssss" runat="server" ValidationGroup="surveyValidate0" SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="question_testsssss" Display="Dynamic" Text="**" ErrorMessage="**" />                                            </div>                                        </div>                                    </ItemTemplate>                                </asp:TemplateField>                            </Columns>                        </asp:GridView>                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddClick" Text="Add Section" OnClick="btn_Click" />                    </ContentTemplate>                </asp:UpdatePanel>            </div>        </asp:View>        <asp:View ID="group_Group2" runat="server">            <div class="group group2">                <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious1_top" runat="server" Text="<< Prev" OnClick="btnPrevious_Click" />                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="surveyValidate1" />            </div>        </asp:View>    </asp:MultiView>

<script type="text/javascript">        function pageLoad(sender, args) {            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {                $('table > tbody > tr .wrapper [class*="onoff"] option:selected').each(function (index) {                    adjustValidators(this);                });            }        }        function adjustValidators(ctrl) {            var id = ctrl.parentNode.id.replace('_question', '_rfv_question').replace('ONOFF', 'testsssss')            //            alert(ctrl.value);            if (ctrl.value == -1) {                ValidatorEnable(eval(id), false)            }            else {                ValidatorEnable(eval(id), true)            }        }    </script>
```

**Default.aspx.cs.**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == -1) ? 0 : MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex;

    DataTable objData =new DataTable();
    if (ViewState["data"] != null)
    {
        objData = (DataTable)ViewState["data"];
    }
    else
    {
        objData = new DataTable();
        objData.Columns.Add("testsssss");
        objData.Columns.Add("ONOFF");
        objData.Columns.Add("ONOFF_selectedValue");
        objData.Rows.Add(objData.NewRow());
        ViewState["data"] = objData;
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        repeatregion_RRSectionSS.DataSource = objData;
        repeatregion_RRSectionSS.DataBind();
    }

}
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex += 1;
}

protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex -= 1;
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable objData = (DataTable)ViewState["data"];

    objData.Rows.Add(objData.NewRow());
    repeatregion_RRSectionSS.DataSource = objData;
    repeatregion_RRSectionSS.DataBind();
    ViewState["data"] = objData;
}
```

when Click on add then item get added to gridview but validators are not disabled.

Thanks and Regards
Sadiq Modan

Comment: Anyone have any Idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trickery I found the solution: replace `eval` in  `ValidatorEnable(eval(id), false)` with `document.getElementById(id)`. It worked for me.